# How do I specify exactly where a border will be postionioned?

Tags: java, swing

I would like the border to be around the text area rather than inside of it.
[image]

```
/**
   This frame shows a data set and its statistics.
 */
public class FileGUI extends JFrame
{  

    private static JPanel panel;
    private JTextArea display;
    private JButton open;
    private JButton save;
    private JButton clear;


    //declare data fields here (GUI Components and other data fields)


    public FileGUI()
    {       

        //Initialize data fields and construct GUI  

        open = new JButton("Open file");
        save = new JButton("Save to File");
        clear = new JButton("Clear Display");

        display = new JTextArea(30,30);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("File Summary");
        display.setBorder(border);



        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(open);
        panel.add(save);
        panel.add(clear);
        panel.add(display);
    }

    //supporting methods here.


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        JFrame frame = new FileGUI();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(panel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the border to enclose your textfield you have to wrap it into another component (e.g. a JPanel) and set the border on that component. Borders are always rendered within the bounds of the components you assign them to.

By the way: You're creating and initializing swing components from the main thread. This is not a good way to do it. Swing is a single threaded GUI and requires all interactions to happen on the event dispatch thread. I recommend the [concurrency in swing lesson](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)